# Members and Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, member

I am reading some open-source code, and am confused by the use of pointers. Can anybody help me analyze the following code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < podRecords; i++)
{
    WaterRight *pRight = new WaterRight;
    pRight->m_reachComid = m_podDb.GetAsInt(m_colReachComid, i);
    int reachID = pRight->m_reachComid;
```

So, my understanding is that by creating `new WaterRight`, the memory that stores the address of `WaterRight` members is dynamically allocated. Then the value (or address?) of `m_colReachComid` is assigned to `m_reachComid`, and then assigned to `reachID`. I am always not sure which identifier is the address and which is the value. For example, is `reachID` an integer value, or is it an address that stores the value?

Comment: Read some good [C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) and some good [tour of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html). Use Linux. Then compile the code with warnings & debugging enabled `g++ -Wall -g`  and use the `gdb` debugger (e.g. to put a breakpoint then step each statement)

Comment: For people first trying to get into C++, I would really not recommend `gdb` immediately...

Comment: I am using visual studio. I don't think I am going to be a programmer/software developer, but I have to know some basics since I am using codes from others without documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`reachID` is an `int` *value*. You store numbers there.

`pRight` is a *pointer to a WaterRight*. It stores the address of some `WaterRight`.

`pRight->m_reachComid` is also an `int` *value*. Specifically it is the `m_reachComid` field of the `WaterRight` instance pointed to by `pRight`.

So:

```
WaterRight *pRight = new WaterRight;
// pRight is a *pointer to a WaterRight instance*: 
// you use pRight->m_reachComid to access the instance's m_reachComid field
pRight->m_reachComid = m_podDb.GetAsInt(m_colReachComid, i);

WaterRight right;
// right is a *WaterRight instance* 
// you use pRight.m_reachComid to access the instance's m_reachComid field
pRight.m_reachComid = m_podDb.GetAsInt(m_colReachComid, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `WaterRight *pRight = new WaterRight;` declares a pointer to an object of a class called `WaterRight` that was just initialized using the default constructor of that class. This class has a member variable called `m_reachComid` which is set in your next line as the return value of `m_podDb.GetAsInt(m_colReachComid, i)` (whatever that function may be). Finally, you declare `reachId` (an integer) and set it equal to whatever value is in your `m_reachComid` variable. But as Basile says in the comments, you really should start with a [good tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) or a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you all. Yes. I should start with a good book. Actually I've read some tutorial for beginners. I thought I understand pointers once, but without practice, it is very easy to return to 0.

Answer (score 0):

reachID is an int, pRight is a pointer the "->" causes a derefernce of the pointer
"pRight->m_reachComid" could be rewriten as "(*pRight).m_reachComid"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **GetAsInt** may return one of these case:

#### Case 1, type check ok (integer as expected)

If `pRight->m_reachComid` is integer, you are right:

```
int reachID = pRight->m_reachComid; // int <- int
```

#### Case 2, type check wrong

If it's not, and `pRight->m_reachComid` is another variable (struct, class, but not pointers) you will receive an error (size is different)
   int reachID = pRight->m_reachComid; // int <- ???

#### Case 3, storing a pointer inside an int

If `pRight->m_reachComid` is a pointer to something, for example a pointer to int, you will receive a **warning**
But you will able to store a pointer inside an integer (not a great idea, it's quite stupid/useless/dangerous), because (in 32bit mode!!) 
`sizeof(int) = 4` and `sizeof(int*) = sizeof(anyType*) = sizeof(void*) = 4`

#### Case 4, storing with cast

If `pRight->m_reachComid` is double or float, you can cast it (and truncate the decimal part)

```
int reachID = (int)pRight->m_reachComid;
```

However, **`int reachID` IS an integer, you can store everything inside but it will always be an integer**